# Пошаговое сохранение загружаемых файлов

Tags: golang

пример кода из книги "Go на практике":

```
mr, err := r.MultipartReader()
if err != nil {
    panic("Failed to read multipart message: ")
}

length := r.ContentLength
for {
    part, err := mr.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    var read int64
    var p float32

    filename := part.FileName()
    dst, err := os.Create("/tmp/dstfile." + filename)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for {
        buffer := make([]byte, 100000)
        cBytes, err := part.Read(buffer)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        read = read + int64(cBytes)
        //fmt.Printf("read: %v \n",read )
        p = float32(read) / float32(length) * 100
        fmt.Printf("progress: %v \n", p)
        dst.Write(buffer[0:cBytes])
    }
}
```

[полный код](https://github.com/Masterminds/go-in-practice/blob/master/chapter7/file_increment_save_notes.go)

Пытаюсь загрузить файлы вот этим способом. В итоге создается 2 фала, один из которых просто `dstfile`, другой `dstfile.name.extension` (прим.: `dstfile.test.txt`). Я пробовал загрузить 2 типа фалов - `.txt` - который получается пустой, и `.xls` - который в общем не открывается.

В общем,по большей степени интересует почему не открывается `.xls`.

Использую windows 10, go1.8 windows/amd64

PS: конкретного этого кода в ру книге нет.

Answer (score 1):

Отрефакторенный вариант.

Лишний файл создавался из-за того, что отсутствовала проверка на пустоту имени файла.

А файлы записывались не корректно, я так думаю, из-за того, что `part.Read` дойдя до конца файла, вываливал ошибку, а то, что он считал не дописывалось. Вот и выходило, что файлы были кривые.

Если не прав, поправьте.

```
mr, err := r.MultipartReader()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}

length := r.ContentLength
for {
    part, err := mr.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        continue
    }

    formName := part.FormName()
    if formName == "" {
        continue
    }

    fileName := part.FileName()
    if fileName == "" {
        continue
    }

    var read int64
    var p float32

    dst, err := os.Create("tmp/dstfile." + fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    buffer := make([]byte, 100000)

    for {
        n, err := part.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            log.Println(err)
            break
        }
        if n == 0 {
            break
        }

        read = read + int64(n)
        //log.Printf("read: %v \n",read )
        p = float32(read) / float32(length) * 100

        _, err = dst.Write(buffer[:n])
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            break
        }

        log.Printf("progress: %v \n", p)
    }

    dst.Close()
}
```